# Por que me sale este error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, sql

Estoy desarrollando un programa con la consulta en una base de datos, esto para verificar si se encuentra usuario y contraseña para el inicio de sesión, pero me salta este error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at modelo.dao.InicioSesion.accesoAdmin(InicioSesion.java:25)
    at modelo.Logica.validarAcceso(Logica.java:18)
    at controlador.Acción.actionPerformed(Acción.java:36)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener$Actions.actionPerformed(BasicButtonListener.java:303)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1663)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2882)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2929)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2845)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6310)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1954)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:806)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1074)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:945)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:771)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4760)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Código de botón:

```
public class InicioSesion {

    public void accesoAdmin(Administrador user)
    {
        Conexion conectar = new Conexion();
        try 
        {
            PreparedStatement consulta = conectar.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM administrador where usuario = ? and contraseña = ? ");
            consulta.setString(1, user.getUsuario());
            consulta.setString(2, user.getContraseña());
            ResultSet res = consulta.executeQuery();
            if(res.next()){  
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Acceso aceptado!!");
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ingrese usuario o contraseña valido!");
            }
            res.close();
            conectar.desconectar();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error, no se conecto");
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Código de conexión:

```
public class Conexion {
   static String bd = "bdcontrolacceso";
   static String login = "root";
   static String password = "";
   static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/"+bd;

   Connection conn = null;
   public Conexion() {
      try{
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,login,password);

         if (conn!=null){
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conexión a base de datos "+bd+" OK");
         }
      }
      catch(SQLException e){
         System.out.println(e);
      }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
         System.out.println(e);
      }catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println(e);
      }
   }
   public Connection getConnection(){
      return conn;
   }

   public void desconectar(){
      conn = null;
   }
}
```

Adjunto el código de la conexión a la base de datos, el código de la problematica que se esta generando con las lineas de comando donde se genera dicho problema y por ultimo el código del botón donde al presionar se realiza la consulta a nuestra base de datos. desconozco por que me este surgiendo este error y agradecería que me ayudaran y explicaran por que se genera para de igual manera tenerlo en cuenta y no estar cometiendo este error ya que es la primera ves que me salta ese error.

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException... y esta clase la mandaste?

Comment: Ya lo solucione, no estaba incluyendo la librería de mysql por lo que me estaba generando ese error.

Comment: Cuál es la línea 25?

Answer (score 0):

Tu error te dice

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Osea que no encuentra la clase Driver para tu mysl, sin ella no podrás hacer la conexión con la base de datos.

El segundo error que te marca

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Es porque siempre asumes que va a funcionar y por ello encadenaste llamadas en

```
PreparedStatement consulta = conectar.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM administrador where usuario = ? and contraseña = ? ");
```

En este caso como conectar no va a poder establecer una conexión debido al primer problema nos regresará null.

el código es como si quedara

```
null.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM administrador where usuario = ? and contraseña = ? ");
```

Allí es más obvio el ver el por qué de ese error, no se le puede pedir a un objeto nulo que realice alguna acción.

Te comparto dos enfoques para manejar este tipo de fallos:

primero, la vieja confiable, comparar con nulo a todo lo que le vayas a hacer llamadas

```
if(conexion != null)
```

te implicará crear más variables, pero nada realmente grave pasa con ello.

La segunda es usar la clase `Optional` de java 8 en adelante, que te permite manejo de nulos de una manera muy eficiente y puedes seguir usando cadenas de llamadas ya que si algo es nulo esa clase se encargará de no hacer las llamadas posteriores.